# Reverse engineering list of columns referred to in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reference, view

I have SQL queries that I would like to know which tables and columns are referred to in the query. For example from this

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%EmployeeID%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

I would like to know that from sys.tables, columns *name*, OBJECT_ID are referred and so on; sys.columns has OBJECT_ID and *name* referred to.

The real query that I got from queries/view definitions are much more than this but this serves as an example.

Is there anyway I can achieve this ?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this is to parse the SQL script itself and return the tables and columns.  There are a number of paid solutions that will do this for you, such as [General SQL Parser](http://sqlparser.com/products.php) (plus many more [via google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=get%20tables%20and%20columns%20from%20sql%20script&oq=get%20tables%20and%20columns%20from%20sql%20script&aqs=chrome..69i57.10087j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=parse%20sql%20script) such as the free python based [SQLParse](http://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/)) or if you only need to do this a couple times you can use their online demo version here: http://107.170.101.241:8080/getTableColumn/ (Top link from [here](http://sqlparser.com/livedemo.php)).

Obviously you could code your own solution using tools like [SMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms162169.aspx) or simply trying to build your own logic, but that's a whole lot of effort...

Comment: Thanks @iamdave for your answer. Will these solutions take into account variations of SQL scripts. For example even a generated script (that has been designed using designer) have several variations, sometimes  [tab1].col1, tab1.col1, "tabl1".col1, other times just column names because column names are not ambiguous in join., e.g Select col1, B.col2 from A a join B b instead of always full reference a.col1, b.col2.

Comment: @Kenny If it is part of the correct SQL Syntax then yes it should.  Easiest way to find out is to try the demo and see for yourself, though if you are not sure, you could use an SQL Formatter such as ApexSQL (free SSMS plugin) to reformat your scripts before putting them into the tools above.